# Expectation of the number of tail seen before the 11th head

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

#### Question

An unfair coin with P(head) = 3/4, toss until seen 11 heads.
Let R be the number of tail seen before the 11th head.What is E[R]?

Below is the answer, but I don't get it. Can someone explain it like I'm 8 years old? Why it's geometrically distributed? Why -11?

[image]

Comment: Find the expectation of the number of failures (i.e. tails) that precede a first success (i.e. a head). This clearly involves geometric distribution (google it). This happens $11$ times, so...Btw, the third equality in the answer is not correct. Minus $11$ is there because in the answer they go for the expectation of the number of trials. To get the failures the $11$ successes (heads) must be subtracted.

Comment: Hi @drhab, can you explain more about x11(independent), why we call it independent?

Comment: Why E[success] is 11?

Comment: Because you stop after exactly $11$ heads. You are asked to find the expectation of $T_1+T_2+T_3+\dots+T_{11}$ where $T_1$ denotes the number of tails (failures) that show up before the first head (success) appears, $T_2$ the number of tails that appear after the first head and the second head, et cetera. You can do that by applying linearity of expectation (there is independence but that is irrelevant because linearity of expectation can also be applied without independence). Each of the $T_i$ has geometric distribution and all have the same expectation (so you get $11$ times the same expecta

Comment: You start tossing a coin until the first Head appears. Denote the number of tosses by $X$. If $ X = n, n \geq 1 $, i.e, first $n-1 $ tosses result in failure and last one, i.e., the $n$-th toss results in success. Next the distribution of $ X $? Clearly, $ \mathbb{P} ( X = n ) = q^{n-1} p $, as we have just described.  This is a geometric r.v. with $ \mathbb{E} (X) = 1/p $. But, as we have described out of $X$, only $1$ is a Head, and rest are Tails. To get 11 such heads, you will do this experiment 11 times, each independent. So, you have the number of tails $ 11 \times \mathbb{E} (X-1) $.

Comment: crystal clear, thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an arithmetic error in your book. The answer is
$11(4/3-1)=11/3$. Read [1] with care and it will be clear.

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution